# If I'm a web server, for which accounts can I turn off shells within passwd file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security

I am making a web server running LAMP and want to access it using SSH.

When I open the `passwd` file, I see all those accounts and I want to know for which ones I can put `false`. I have the following accounts:

```
root, daemon, bin, sys, sync, games, man, lp, mail, news, uucp, proxy, www-data
backup, list, irc, gnats, nobody, libuuid, syslog, messagebus, whoopsie, 
mandscape, sshd, eric
```

Except `root`, `sshd` and `eric`, which ones should I not disable?
How about `www-data` and `sshd`?

Comment: `Note: the sshd account was set to nologin shell, and yet I was able to connect to SSH normally.` - As the sshd user?

Comment: @MDMarra Wondering about that also, how would OP get the password for user sshd without resetting it?

Comment: @jscott I'm assuming that OP just doesn't understand how those accounts work and what setting the default shell actually does, but it doesn't hurt to make sure.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm a beginner, and have searched various ways of securing the server. Locking those accounts, being one of them. Regards

Comment: Why is there even an account named "games"? This isn't on a server, is it?

Comment: Hi John, this games account came with the stock version of Ubuntu latest version. Regards

Comment: You didn't answer my question

Comment: Hi, I actually thought that the sshd account was linked to ssh. I didn't have the sshd password at any time. Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few misconceptions, both on how the login system works and what the purpose of these accounts is.

First, most of these accounts, with the exception of `root` and `eric`, are system accounts that are not meant for people to login but allow different services to run as ordinary users without all the privileges the `root` account has. As an example, the OpenSSH daemon usually runs as user `sshd`, so if anyone would manage to gain control over the `sshd` process, it would allow him only to access and modify the files for which the corresponding user `sshd` has permissions.

Second, the preferred way to disable login for a user is to disable his password and not to change the login shell to `/bin/false`. On modern Linux systems, the user database actually consists of two parts, `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`. The password is stored in `/etc/shadow` (see below for why), and an account is disabled if its password field in `/etc/shadow` is an `*`.

In the following example, the user `sshd` is disabled, while `sven` has an encrypted password set. You can't login as user `sshd`, neither via the console nor an ssh session, but login for `sven` will work.

```
sshd:*:15533:0:99999:7:::
sven:$6$ckP43saI2$Xjoxh52LLJxz2VXa.:15538:0:99999:7:::
```

Most likely, you will find that *all* users on your system, with the exception of `eric` (and maybe `root`) are disabled this way, which means that what you want to accomplish has already been done by the developers. Also, you will find that many accounts also have their login shell already set to `/bin/false` in `/etc/passwd`, which means that even root can't use `su' to switch to these accounts.

---

Why the separation of `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`?

Many programs need to access the user database for various purposes, but giving read access to `/etc/passwd` allowed everyone to read the encrypted passwords of all users, which is highly insecure, especially as the encryption of the passwords was quite weak for a long time. This was solved by putting the passwords into the separate file `/etc/shadow`, which is only readable by root.

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot for your detailed and clear response. Regards